# How to move the first four elements of an arraylist into another arraylist?

Tags: java, arraylist

This is my deck class:

```
public class Deck {    
    ArrayList<Card> deck = new ArrayList<Card>();    
    public ArrayList<Card> get32Cards() {    
        deck.add(new Card(Suit.SPADES, Rank.JACK));
        deck.add(new Card(Suit.SPADES, Rank.KING));
        deck.add(new Card(Suit.SPADES, Rank.SEVEN));
        deck.add(new Card(Suit.SPADES, Rank.EIGHT));
        deck.add(new Card(Suit.SPADES, Rank.NINE));
        deck.add(new Card(Suit.SPADES, Rank.TEN));
        deck.add(new Card(Suit.SPADES, Rank.ACE));
        deck.add(new Card(Suit.SPADES, Rank.QUEEN));
        deck.add(new Card(Suit.HEARTS, Rank.JACK));
        deck.add(new Card(Suit.HEARTS, Rank.KING));
        deck.add(new Card(Suit.HEARTS, Rank.SEVEN));
        deck.add(new Card(Suit.HEARTS, Rank.EIGHT));
        deck.add(new Card(Suit.HEARTS, Rank.NINE));
        deck.add(new Card(Suit.HEARTS, Rank.TEN));
        deck.add(new Card(Suit.HEARTS, Rank.ACE));
        deck.add(new Card(Suit.HEARTS, Rank.QUEEN));
        deck.add(new Card(Suit.CLUBS, Rank.JACK));
        deck.add(new Card(Suit.CLUBS, Rank.KING));
        deck.add(new Card(Suit.CLUBS, Rank.SEVEN));
        deck.add(new Card(Suit.CLUBS, Rank.EIGHT));
        deck.add(new Card(Suit.CLUBS, Rank.NINE));
        deck.add(new Card(Suit.CLUBS, Rank.TEN));
        deck.add(new Card(Suit.CLUBS, Rank.ACE));
        deck.add(new Card(Suit.CLUBS, Rank.QUEEN));
        deck.add(new Card(Suit.DIAMONDS, Rank.JACK));
        deck.add(new Card(Suit.DIAMONDS, Rank.KING));
        deck.add(new Card(Suit.DIAMONDS, Rank.SEVEN));
        deck.add(new Card(Suit.DIAMONDS, Rank.EIGHT));
        deck.add(new Card(Suit.DIAMONDS, Rank.NINE));
        deck.add(new Card(Suit.DIAMONDS, Rank.TEN));
        deck.add(new Card(Suit.DIAMONDS, Rank.ACE));
        deck.add(new Card(Suit.DIAMONDS, Rank.QUEEN));

        Collections.shuffle(deck); //this shuffles the deck

        return deck;
    }
}
```

and this is my main class:

```
public class Game {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Card> deck = new ArrayList<Card>();

        Deck getdeck = new Deck();
        deck = getdeck.get32Cards();

        for (Card info : deck) {
            System.out.println(info);
        }  
    }
}
```

I have a piece of code that i think will work, but not sure how to implement it, or if it is even right:

```
 public boolean giveFourCards(Card c) {
        for (int x = 1; x < 3; x++) {
            if (deck.contains(c)) {
                deck.remove(c);
                Hand1.add(c);
                return true;
            } else
                return false;
        }
        return false;    
    }
```

I want to copy the first 4 elements of the 'deck' arraylist into another arraylist called 'hand1', and then remove those 4 elements from the 'deck' arraylist.

Comment: If you return in the first iteration of a loop, the rest of the loop will not be run.

Comment: Alternatively, how about using a `Queue` instead of an `ArrayList`? Might be more "natural" for a deck of cards. Also, you could use two nested loops for populating the deck...

Answer (score 1):

Your giveFourCards() method receive a Card instance as a parameter : why ?

Your for loop seems wrong : should be `for (int x=0; x<4; x++) {`.

You seem to have copied block of code that you have not understood.

As I understand your question it should be:

```
public boolean giveFourCards() {
    for (int x=0; x<4; x++) {
        if (!deck.isEmpty()) {
            Hand1.add(deck.removeFirst());
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: You should also add parameters for `deck` and `hand`. The `deck` is a local variable (although is could be a class member), but you definitely need the `hand` parameter since there are probably more than one player to deal cards to.

Answer (score 1):

if you want get first 4 cards from deck then you can

```
public ArrayList<Card> giveFourCards() {
       ArrayList<Card> hand=new ArrayList<Card>();
       for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
            hand.add(deck.get(x));  
       }
    return hand;

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Two problems:

1. you are returning after the first iteration
2. you are testing is a given card is in the deck?

This may correct the problems:

```
public giveFourCards(Hand h) {
  for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
    h.add(deck.remove(0)); // push the removed card into the hand
  }
}
```

Comment: 1) There is no `remove()` with no parameters on `ArrayList`; 2) loop should go to `4`; 3) `Hand` is the class (what class?), so it should rather be `h.add`

Comment: Corrected, sorry for the mistakes